# jax-rs or condition with filters @provider

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm in this situation and searching on doc and also here i have not found an answer.

I have a Jersey 2 web API and i have 3 filters tagged `@Provider`: the first one is for authentication and it works great; the second one and the third one are to tag endpoint for specific type of user, so I have `@Admin` and `@User` that differentiate which operation can do an admin and which can do a normal user.

I chose this method (check the type of user with a filter) to let the endpoint clear and the only code on it is just the operation that it needs to do.

So the problem is that if I tag a method (or a class) with both `@Admin` and `@User`, Jersey execute both the filters but they are in conflict because the `@Admin` let you do the operation only if you are `@Admin` and `@User` let you do the operation only if you are a normal user (so whatever is the first filter is going to be executed, assume is `@Admin`, if I'm a normal user and try to access to that method, I just can't).

I can't leave both the annotations because i could have a third kind of user which can't access to that endpoint, so my question is: is it possible to put in OR condition two filters? So in the example I write before my idea is that both filters are executed but if one tell me I'm authenticated, I can access to that endpoint and if both fails, so I can't use that endpoint.

Thank to all will answer to this question!

Comment: You can create another annotation and pass a list of user types allowed to access the resource, but sooner or later you will end with a custom implementation of https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/security.html#annotation-based-security or spring security or another similar already existing technology.

Comment: Great thanks! This was my last option, but honestly I think it's the cleaner one! Thanks again